# Where is the "official description" of Windows Forms events?

Tags: .net, events, forms

I've found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983610(VS.71).aspx), but it doesn't look very much complete. Also, the description in Visual Studio about the events is mostly ambiguous. I don't want to go on a trial and error rampage to find things out.

I'm particularly interested in the events related to exit/abort from a Form.

EDIT: I know events are part of the framework and not specific to Windows Forms, but I'm interested in the events Windows Forms components raise, in particular Forms themselves.

Comment: See my edit for the list of events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this MSDN article: [Order of events in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d.aspx)? It lists all the events to do with application shutdown - that includes the events raised on forms when they close.

Answer (score 1):

Events are not just for Windows Forms. They are fundamental constructs in the CLI and have a representation in C#. Take a look at the [Events Tutorial here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28VS.71%29.aspx) as a starting place.

For Windows Forms, most of the events are declared on the [Control class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control_events.aspx) (a base class of Form). The [Form class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form_events.aspx) also has several of its own, as do many of the controls.

Comment: But I want to know about especifically about the events Windows Forms expose, not about events in general.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this: [MouseDown Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedown.aspx)?

Or, better, [Forms Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form_events.aspx).